# JQuery If Block inside setTimeout function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive done a bit of searching and nothings given me an answer here.

On a page I am building, I am making it that you login once in the main area (its all in one page and each link just brings in a div  that was hidden).

I have an admin area, that i want the button for to be hidden until you log in as an admin,

I have set in my php that if the login as admin is successful that it creates a hidden checkbox that is checked if you are an admin, is not checked if not an admin.

```
    $("#adminlogin").submit(function() {
    setTimeout (function() {
        if ($('#admintrue').is(':checked')){
            $('#adminbutton').show('fade',500); 
        } else {
            $('#adminbutton').hide('fade',500);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

I tried to do this (because the jquery acts quicker than the php) but from what I can see you cannot put an if query inside a setTimeout function.

Does anyone have a way I can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: it's more likely to do with the fact that this is in a `submit` handler. Once you submit a page, the browser redirects to whatever the forms `action` is ... no asynchronous code like that in the setTimeout will stop it

Comment: question is not clear. everything works in setTimeout

Comment: @RanjitSingh - not if it's in a `submit` event handler - it'll never run if the form submits

Comment: @JaromandaX - yup that is true

Comment: the form is submitting to itself with this `<form action=" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "  method='POST'>`

Comment: yes, so it's reloading the page, the code that was to run after the setTimeout is no longer going to run, because it's a **new page**

Comment: Ahh thank you guys very much, i just set it to run on the document.ready (the if block only) and it works!

I cant believe I didnt think to try that :/ 

Much appreciated everyone :)

Comment: I was just typing that you should do it in document ready :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead:

```
...
 if($('#admintrue:checked')) {
...
```

Also, you can use a class/id instead of the hidden checkbox and it can be checked as following:

```
...
if($('#myID')) {
...
```

or

```
...
if($('#myElement').hasClass('my-class')) {
...
```

Comment: The :checked check was working, but I like your method of minimizing the code. Jaromanda hit the nail on the head in other comments, it was because the form submission was refreshing the page and effectively stopping the event handler.